# Coomunication between two controllers which is open in different web browsers of two different or same divces

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

Actually I am trying to create inbox like GMAIL. But I am unable to show received message as soon as sender send that message. I am using angularjs and codeigniter.

I have two controller's sender and receiver. As soon as sender send message I am  updating scope variables of receiver controller. But it is not working.

My sender Controller send message function -

```
$scope.send_message_toCustomer = function(counselor_id,thread_title) {  
    var thread_id=$('#threadid').val();
    //console.log(thread_id);
        $scope.inboxMessage.message=$scope.message;
        $scope.inboxMessage.thread_id=thread_id;
        var request = $http({
            method:"POST",
            url: site_url+"thread/insert_thread_message",
            data : $scope.inboxMessage,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }    
        });
        request.success(function($data){
                //console.log($data);
                if($data==1)
             {
                $scope.message='';
                            getCustomerChildThread.getChildThread().success(function($data) 
                {
                    //console.log($data);
                    $scope.C_Thread = angular.copy($data);              
                }); 
                $('#inbox_sub_menu').css('display', 'block');
                $('#s_menu').addClass('open');
                //$timeout(function() {
                    $scope.inbox_aco_thread.thread_id=thread_id;
                    var request = $http({
                        method:"POST",
                        url: site_url+"thread/inbox_thread",
                        data : $scope.inbox_aco_thread,
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }    
                    });
                     request.success(function($data){
                             $('#thread_msg_count_'+thread_id).removeClass('msg_count');
                                     $scope.inbox_messages=angular.copy($data);
                                     $scope.inbox_messages.counselor_id=angular.copy(counselor_id);
                                     $scope.inbox_messages.thread_id=angular.copy(thread_id);
                                     $scope.inbox_messages.thread_title=angular.copy(thread_title);
                            });
                            //}, 500);
                         }
                     });

               };
```

After that function I want to update my receiver controller scope. My receiver controller get messages function-

```
$scope.inbox_cust_thread=function(customer_id,thread_id,thread_title)
{
    $('#thread_msg_count_'+thread_id).removeClass('msg_count');
    $scope.main_threadview=true;
    $scope.add_threadview=false;
    $scope.cust_thread.loading = false;                 
    $scope.inbox_cu_thread.counselor_id=counselor_id;
    $scope.inbox_cu_thread.thread_id=thread_id;
    var request = $http({
                method:"POST",
                url: site_url+"Customer_thread/inbox_thread",
                data : $scope.inbox_cu_thread,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }    
            });
             request.success(function($data){
                 //$('#thread_msg_count_'+thread_id).addClass('msg_count');
                 $scope.cust_inbox_messages=$data;
                 $scope.cust_inbox_messages.customer_id=customer_id;
                 $scope.cust_inbox_messages.thread_id=thread_id;
                 $scope.cust_inbox_messages.thread_title=thread_title;
                 //$scope.cust_inbox_messages.counselor_id=counselor_id;
        });
};
```

Anybody please help me.

Comment: check with $apply after updating scope variables....it would be really helpful if u post your code or create a plunker or fiddle to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible, you have to store the messages in a database then in angularjs you have to do a request every minutes for example to check if there is new messages.

Answer (score 1):

[Here the Demo For auto updating the value based on time](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uk5cmzOQM9m15H33rhcq?p=preview)

```
I think it will useful for you.once you send the data from sender. receiver need to auto update. it will useful to what need to acheive.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to track the browser session for each tab and then push the mail to the active tab of that session. Try to research on how to uniquely identify active browser tab in client and push data to those tabs. This could be the logic you are looking. Because you cannot share information between controllers of different tabs as the Application context is different in different tabs.